# É possível injetar um bean em um singleton com enum?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee-7

Nós temos um sistema que usa Struts 1 e singletons baseados em enums.

Agora temos uma dependência que foi escrita usando Spring 4.3.6.RELEASE que deveria ser usado somente com outros sistemas que também usam Spring, por isso todas as dependências Spring declaradas têm seu escopo como provided.

Agora o sistema que usa Struts 1 deve usar essa dependência. Eu declarei todas as dependências Spring necessárias, criei meu applicationContext, mas infelizmente eu não sou capaz de injetar os beans nos meus singletons porque eles são enums.

Essas dependência não me oferece rest services.

Segue meu applicationContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:/applicationContext-dependency.xml" />

</beans>
```

Aqui uma classe que demonstra meu problema:

```
public enum ItemRemessaUtil {

    INSTANCIA;

    @Autowired
    private BeneficiarioBS beneficiarioBS;

    @Autowired
    private ItemRemessaBS itemRemessaBS;

    @Autowired
    public Boleto inserirItemRemessaMultaDesassociacao(final MultaBean multa) throws BOException, DataAccessException {
        return this.inserirItemRemessa(multa.getNroFatura(), multa.getNossoNumeroItemRemessa(),
                multa.getDataEmissaoBoleto(), multa.getDataVencimentoBoleto(),
                multa.getValorFatura().subtract(multa.getValorDesconto()), multa.getComprador(), TipoOrigem.MULTA);
    }

    @Autowired
    public Boleto inserirItemRemessaOrdemCancelamento(final OrdCancelBean ordCancel)
            throws BOException, DataAccessException {
        return this.inserirItemRemessa(ordCancel.getNrOrdCancel(), ordCancel.getNossoNumeroItemRemessa(),
                ordCancel.getDataEmissaoBoleto(), ordCancel.getDataVencimentoBoleto(),
                BigDecimal.valueOf(ordCancel.getVlOrdem()), ordCancel.getComprd(), TipoOrigem.CANCELAMENTO_VT);
    }

    @Autowired
    private Boleto inserirItemRemessa(final long numeroPedido, final Long nossoNumeroItemRemessa,
            final Date dataDocumento, final Date dataVencimentoBoleto, final BigDecimal valorTotal,
            final ComprdBean comprdBean, final TipoOrigem tipoOrigem) throws BOException, DataAccessException {
        final Boleto boleto = BoletoBancarioFactory.criarBoletoSantander(
                this.beneficiarioBS.construirBeneficiario(tipoOrigem, ConstantesBoleto.CNPJ_RIOPAR, numeroPedido,
                        nossoNumeroItemRemessa, dataVencimentoBoleto),
                BoletoUtil.construirPagador(comprdBean),
                Datas.novasDatas(dataDocumento,
                        TipoOrigem.MULTA.equals(tipoOrigem)
                                ? ParamMultaDesassociacaoBO.retornarQuantidadeDiasVencimentoMultaDesassociacao()
                                : ConstantesBoleto.QUANTIDADE_DIAS_VENCIMENTO_BOLETO_SANTANDER),
                valorTotal);

        if (nossoNumeroItemRemessa == null
                || DateUtil.retornarDataSemHorario(dataVencimentoBoleto).before(boleto.getDatas().getVencimento())) {
            this.itemRemessaBS.inserirItemRemessa(boleto);
        }

        return boleto;
    }
}
```

Eu já li algumas das perguntas do SO americano como [Inject bean into enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318454/inject-bean-into-enum) e [Using Singleton enum in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521352/using-singleton-enum-in-spring-mvc) e tentei as soluções listadas, porém meus atributos da enum nunca são injetados e, infelizmente, somente através deles eu consigo entrar na dependência.

O que eu posso fazer para injetar as dependências desses atributos?

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais prática de você injetar as dependencias dentro de enum é criar um componente que ira realmente setar essas dependencais para serem utilizadas conforme abaixo:

```
public enum ItemRemessaUtil {

    INSTANCIA;

    private BeneficiarioBS beneficiarioBS;
    private ItemRemessaBS itemRemessaBS;

    public Boleto inserirItemRemessaMultaDesassociacao(final MultaBean multa) throws BOException, DataAccessException {
        return this.inserirItemRemessa(multa.getNroFatura(), multa.getNossoNumeroItemRemessa(),
                multa.getDataEmissaoBoleto(), multa.getDataVencimentoBoleto(),
                multa.getValorFatura().subtract(multa.getValorDesconto()), multa.getComprador(), TipoOrigem.MULTA);
    }

    public Boleto inserirItemRemessaOrdemCancelamento(final OrdCancelBean ordCancel)
            throws BOException, DataAccessException {
        return this.inserirItemRemessa(ordCancel.getNrOrdCancel(), ordCancel.getNossoNumeroItemRemessa(),
                ordCancel.getDataEmissaoBoleto(), ordCancel.getDataVencimentoBoleto(),
                BigDecimal.valueOf(ordCancel.getVlOrdem()), ordCancel.getComprd(), TipoOrigem.CANCELAMENTO_VT);
    }

    private Boleto inserirItemRemessa(final long numeroPedido, final Long nossoNumeroItemRemessa,
            final Date dataDocumento, final Date dataVencimentoBoleto, final BigDecimal valorTotal,
            final ComprdBean comprdBean, final TipoOrigem tipoOrigem) throws BOException, DataAccessException {
        final Boleto boleto = BoletoBancarioFactory.criarBoletoSantander(
                this.beneficiarioBS.construirBeneficiario(tipoOrigem, ConstantesBoleto.CNPJ_RIOPAR, numeroPedido,
                        nossoNumeroItemRemessa, dataVencimentoBoleto),
                BoletoUtil.construirPagador(comprdBean),
                Datas.novasDatas(dataDocumento,
                        TipoOrigem.MULTA.equals(tipoOrigem)
                                ? ParamMultaDesassociacaoBO.retornarQuantidadeDiasVencimentoMultaDesassociacao()
                                : ConstantesBoleto.QUANTIDADE_DIAS_VENCIMENTO_BOLETO_SANTANDER),
                valorTotal);

        if (nossoNumeroItemRemessa == null
                || DateUtil.retornarDataSemHorario(dataVencimentoBoleto).before(boleto.getDatas().getVencimento())) {
            this.itemRemessaBS.inserirItemRemessa(boleto);
        }

        return boleto;
    }

    // Componente que irá injetar suas dependencias dentro do enum
    @Component
    public static class ServiceInjector {
        @Autowired
        private BeneficiarioBS beneficiarioBS;

        @Autowired
        private ItemRemessaBS itemRemessaBS;

        @PostConstruct
        public void postConstruct() {
            for (ItemRemessaUtil item : EnumSet.allOf(ItemRemessaUtil.class)) {
                item.setBeneficiarioBS(beneficiarioBS);
                item.setItemRemessaBS(itemRemessaBS);
            }
        }
    }

    // Set's
    private void setBeneficiarioBS(BeneficiarioBS beneficiarioBS) {
        this.beneficiarioBS = beneficiarioBS;
    }

    private void setItemRemessaBS(ItemRemessaBS itemRemessaBS) {
        this.itemRemessaBS = itemRemessaBS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Os sets podem ser privados já que não quero ninguém modificando isso por fora, certo? Acho que sua resposta pode ser a correta pro meu problema!

Comment: a sim, verdade os sets devem ser privados para melhor segurança e controle desta injeções de dependencia

Comment: O ServiceInjector e o método anotado com PostConstruct podem ser privados também, certo? Acredito que o Spring consiga enxergá-los por reflection.

Comment: Sim, os componentes podem ser privados, a unica exigência é que exista [um construtor sem argumentos](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection) ou pelo menos recebendo argumentos com injeção de dependencia `public @Autowired Construtor(Interface i)` por exemplo

Comment: Pode adicionar isso na sua resposta?

Comment: Opa, pode sim, obrigado